# Downsides of using two IoC containers in same solution in .NET?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, structuremap

I am working on a project which uses a set of libraries from some other developer which uses [structuremap](http://structuremap.github.io) as the IoC container. [I have the codebase with me]

The application in which we are incorporating these libraries uses [unity container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff647202(v=pandp.10)).

Is there a downside to having two container frameworks in the same solution? I want to move everything over to the same IoC container but how do I justify the extra effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between having multiple container libraries in the same *solution* vs. the same *application*, since a solution can consist of multiple runnable applications.

All components should be wired in the application's start-up path, a.k.a. the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/):

> A Composition Root is a (preferably) unique location in an application where modules are composed together.

Together with the use of Constructor Injection, the Composition Root pattern keeps your application completely *loosely coupled*, and keeps your application code decoupled from your DI Container.

According to the Composition Root pattern, no other parts of an application should therefore depend on a DI Container. The fact that the libraries that you use do, is problematic, because this forces you into a certain DI Container. A better solution is to make the libraries [DI-friendly](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/).

There are a few downsides to having multiple container libraries in the same *solution*:

- You have to learn two different DI Container libraries, each with their limitations and quirks
- Each library comes with its own risk to needing to be replaced when [development](https://jeremydmiller.com/2018/01/29/sunsetting-structuremap/) [stops](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/08/21/the-future-of-unity/).

On top of that, there are a few downsides to using multiple container libraries in the same *application*:

- Complexities can arise when a single object graph is constructed of application components that come from different containers. It can be hard to visualize object graphs and verify them for correctness.
- If some component is resolved from both containers, it could lead to [Torn Lifestyles](https://simpleinjector.org/diatl)

That's not to say that you should never have multiple containers in the same solution or application. For instance, you could have two containers as a temporary solution, because you are moving from one library to the next, but a big bang migration is too much work. Ideally, you would in that case migrate one application at the time, but even that could be too much to chew off at once.

Another common scenario where having two containers is fine, is when the application framework you are running is using a DI Container internally to build up its services. Common examples of these frameworks are ASP.NET Core and NServiceBus. In that case, to make the distinction clear, I typically talk about the framework's *configuration system* instead of its internal container, since that's what it basically is. It being a container, is an *implementation detail*.

In that case you can leave the built-in 'configuration system' as-is to resolve *framework components*, and use your DI Container of choice to build object graphs of *application components*.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. answered all my queries and more.