# How to add IHttpClientFactory to NInject in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ninject, .net-framework-version

I'm trying to add `IHttpClientFactory` to NInject in my C# **ASP.NET Web Forms** application so that I can use it in services.  There is lots of documentation online about using [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.ihttpclientfactory.createclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0) (and not creating lots of `HttpClient` instances), however:

1. Documentation/Examples are based on using the interface with .NET Core and I'm using ASP.NET (i.e. .NET Framework) e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.0
2. Documentation tends to be about wiring up `IHttpClientFactory` using Microsoft's own dependency injection system rather than NInject.

So, what have I tried? Well, I don't know where to start really as although `IHttpClientFactory` is well defined in the `System.Net.Http` namespace, there is no concrete implementation exposed in which I can bind it to.  I want to write this:

```
public class ClassLibNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory>().ToConstant<System.Net.Http.HttpClientFactory>();
    }
}
```

However:

1. `System.Net.Http.HttpClientFactory` is a static type and it doesn't implement `System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory` (different methods: `CreateClient()` vs `Create()`)
2. I can't seem to get how to bind a service to a static provider.

Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: also has this problem. in my project thera are just NinjectModules. There is no startup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install nuget packages:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Http
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
```

Next add to your global.asax.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace....
....
public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider;

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder();
  hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices);
  var host = hostBuilder.Build();

  ServiceProvider = host.Services;
}

void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddHttpClient(); //extension method that add IHttpClientFactories
   *inject services here*
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Does it matter that I'm using a mixture of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and `Ninject`?

Comment: there are some downsides. Here is some link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50474299/downsides-of-using-two-ioc-containers-in-same-solution-in-net

Comment: I don't think this answer actually solves the problem of using HttpClientFactory with Ninject. To solve It I recommend this article: https://hamidmosalla.com/2020/05/22/using-ihttpclientfactory-with-asp-net-mvc5/